# node/express middleware testing - res.send

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I'm trying to write a test for the following middleware that protects against JSON vulnerability:

```
/**
* JSON vulnerability protection - prepend the data with ")]},\n", 
*/
function protectJSON(req, res, next) {
  res.send = (...args) => _prependAndSend(res, args);
  return next();
}

module.exports = {
 protectJSON,
};

function _prependAndSend(res, args) {
  let body = args[0];
  const statusCode = args[1];
  const contentType = res.getHeader('Content-Type');
  // EDIT: added _send
  const _send = res.send;

  console.log('body', JSON.stringify(body));

  if (contentType && contentType.indexOf('application/json') !== -1) {
    _send.call(res, `)]}',\n${body}`);
  } else {
   _send.apply(res, args);
  }
}
```

so I wrote the test below, but when I ran it I have a crazy loop (res.send is called endlessly).

```
describe('Test suite for middlewares.protectJSON', () => {
  let nextMock;
  let responseStub;

  beforeEach(() => {
    nextMock = sinon.stub();
    responseStub = {
      getHeader: sinon.stub(),
    };
  });

  it('should not prefix content type other than json', () => {
    protectJSON(null, responseStub, nextMock);
    responseStub.send({ data: 'test' });

    expect(responseStub.send).to.have.been.calledWith( data: 'test' });
  });
});
```

When I run the test, I get

```
body {"data":"test-data"}
body {"data":"test-data"}
body {"data":"test-data"}
body {"data":"test-data"}
// more logging
body {"data":"test-data"}
```

I don't know why it behaves like that in order to fix it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What does _send do? Can you extend your code with this function?

Comment: @KorbinianKuhn _send is just a reference to `res.send`. I have accidentally deleted this bit of code while removing comments to post the question. `const _send = res.send` . it's fixed now

Answer (score 0):

fixed it with

```
function protectJSON(req, res, next) {
  const _send = res.send;
  res.send = (...args) => _prependAndSend(res, _send, args);
  return next();
}
```

basically I removed the declaration for `_send` from the `_prependAndSend` method and instead I declared it in the `protectJSON` method then passed it as an argument to the `prependAndSend` method.

```
function _prependAndSend(res, _send, args) {
  let body = args[0];
  const statusCode = args[1];
  const contentType = res.getHeader('Content-Type');

  if (contentType && contentType.indexOf('application/json') !== -1) {
    _send.call(res, `)]}',\n${body}`);
  } else {
    _send.apply(res, args);
  }
}
```